# How to get android native push notification on cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, push, pushsharp

The event on application is being triggered when the server send the notification, but I get only the alert with the message on app, not the native notification.

I am using ionic framework with the $cordovaPush plugin. On the server side I am using PushSharp library to call GCM.

This is the code added to app.js on $ionicPlatform.ready

```js
 var androidConfig = {
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
            alert: true,
            "senderID": "10xxxxxxxxxx"
        };

$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function (result) {
  // Success
}, function (err) {
  // Error
})

$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
  alert('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived');
  switch (notification.event) {
    case 'registered':
      if (notification.regid.length > 0) {
        alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
      }
      break;

    case 'message':
      // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
      alert(JSON.stringify(notification));
      break;

    case 'error':
      alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
      break;

    default:
      alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
      break;
  }
}, false);
```

This is the code from the server (C# + PushSharp lib)

```js
var push = new PushBroker();
//Wire up the events for all the services that the broker registers
push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;

push.RegisterGcmService(new
                        GcmPushChannelSettings("AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));

push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(
  "APAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                       .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"Hello World!\",\"badge\":7,\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used that plugin, but I recommend you this one:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

this is the one most used, and it works like a charm

Comment: You, man, saved my day. Now, I get the notification while the application is closed. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Yes, this happens. You only get the notification in the bar when the app is not in the front. If it is, is launched the onNotification function but is not displayed in the bar. Glad to help, you can upvote or approve the answer ;)